# Recursive method that prints a number vertically

Tags: tail-recursion

I want to write a recursive method let's say "printVertical" that takes as input a positive integer and prints its digits in vertical.
For example the output of the call: printVertical(2849) is:

9

4

8

2

Any help guys?

Comment: and which language will you use?

Comment: Thanks guys for your concern ..


I am using Java..

I tied to convert the number to String and using CharAt to print the first number and substring to pass the remaining ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework? I'll try to guide you.

1) You can convert the int to a string, and then print the right most char and pass the rest of the string to the next recursive iteration - that probably not the best way

2) Use div & mod by 10, 2849 mod 10 gives 9, print it, pass 2849 div 10 to the next iteration, stop when num div 10 = 0

Comment: No, it is an exercise I had for my Data Structure in java exam

I tried the second one and it worked
thanks a lot